# Group algebra for finitely generated group

Tags: linear-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory, definition

I know the definition of a group algebra $k[G]$ for a finite group $G$ as the set of all linear combination of elements in $G$ with coefficients in the field $k$.

Here, it is easy to show that this is a finite-dimensional vector space.

Is there any way to define the group algebra for a finitely generated group and what can be said about it being finitely generated / of finite dimension?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The normal definition of "group algebra" [already includes infinite groups](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Group_ring#Definition).

By design, $\dim_k(k[G])=|G|$, no matter what group it is.

If $G$ is a finitely generated group, then you can say that $k[G]$ is finitely generated as a $k$-algebra, because with a finite subset of $G$ generating $G$ you can reproduce all of $G$, and with their $k$-linear combinations you get all of $k[G]$.